# Concerning SharePoint Home Page how do you change it

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

https://Example.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx How do you edit this page? Is this part of team site?

Comment: Please, could you explain better what is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the proper permissions you can change it through the browser. Gear icon (top right) -> Edit Page. Or if you want to you can through [SharePoint Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491). By default the team site has a home page from the Pages library. Usually it must be checked out before it can be edited, so you must do that first.